# es seguro Flask-login más un ciclo if que consulte el valor de una session['usuario'] para limitar el acceso a una página con información sensible?

Tags: python, flask

La idea es saber que tan seguro es poner una pagina con información sensible de la base de datos utilizando flask-login y un ciclo if que solo permita entrar a un usuario particular, de modo que solo pueda entrar yo.
En esa pagina se podría ver el nombre de los usuarios y se podrian cambiar las contraseñas.
Copio ejemplo de lo que hice, quiero saber si es seguro o si hay una forma mejor para hacerlo (o si conviene evitarlo directamente).

Flask-login como se indica en la pagina oficial.

en las vistas:

```
@app.route("/administrador", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def administrador():
    if session['usuario'] == 'xxx':

        ....
        return render_template('administrador.html.j2', usuario=session['usuario'],...)        

    else:
        return redirect(url_for('otrapagina'))
```

Es lo sufucientemente seguro hacerlo asi? Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo más seguro o es conveniente evitar este tipo de paginas?

Comment: La seguridad de ese método depende de varias cosas: 1) Usas https para la comunicación, o solo http? Si es solo http no hay seguridad ninguna pues tus credenciales de sesión pueden ser capturadas cuando se envían. 2) ¿Cómo se autenticó previamente al usuario? ¿con nombre y contraseña? ¿cómo se guardan esas contraseñas en el servidor? y 3) Flask requiere inicializar un "secreto" que usará para cifrar las cookies de sesión ¿está ese secreto seguro? ¿no habrás hecho público el fuente en algún repositorio?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! te comento, 1) uso https. 2) Se autentica con usuario y contraseña, ambas guardadas en la base de datos en el servidor (mysql) y la contraseña hashed. 3) No guarde el codigo en ningun repositorio aun, y de hacerlo sera en forma privada.